# Ruby On Rails - Lynda.com - Upload tutor files

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to learn ruby on rails using lynda.com.

Lynda provides exercise files for each chapter. This is exactly how your project entitle "simple_cms" should look at that moment.

** My question **

I've made a small error during the project uploading a record to a MYSQL database. How to i delete my files and use the lynda version? This will give me confidence my project is accurate going forward.

I'm assuming 
- delete files 
- bundle install 
- rails db:migrate

My problem: i'm getting error - mysql database already exists.

I'm using latest versions of both ruby on rails and mysql

Comment: Have you attempted to contact support at lynda.com?

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to do this:

```
rake db:drop
```

Which presumes your Rails application is still at least a little functional. If not you have to do it the hard way.

Then you need to connect to MySQL and issue a `DROP DATABASE databasename` where `databasename` is the name of your database.

> Remember this: **MySQL does not ever ask for confirmation and will immediately do anything you request of it without hesitation**. It does not care if you're on a production server or if you've made a mistake. Always double-check your statements before pressing enter. I have a lot of experience with this and I still don't type the `;` to "arm" the statement until I'm confident it will work.

One way to make your development life a little easier if you want to scrap and rebuild all the time is to use something like [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) if you're familiar with something like Linux. You can blow up the entire VM any time you've made too much of a mess of it, then bring it back up with `vagrant up`. Worth looking into if you're starting a lot of little throw-away projects you just want to experiment with, but not have cluttering up your machine permanently.